# upgrade winform application not overwriting XML file even when "Always Copy"

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-setup-proje, deployment-project

I have an winform application say StackOverflow.exe. When I upgrade the latest release from StackOverflow.exe version 1.1 to version 1.2, its not overwriting XML file(say plugin.xml) from output content folder.

Note: plugin.xml is overwriten everytime i close StackOverflow.exe.

Comment: The context of your question is unclear. Is this failure to overwrite in a setup project, such as MSI file that's running to install and update files?  Or is it at build time?  Anyway, if the XML file is in use by your exe then it can't be replaced while you have it open.

Comment: I installed our winform application. This exe package contains an xml file. I have manually overwritten the XML file as per my requirement. Now I get the new release of this application. When I install this latest release, it is supposed to replace the xml file available within the latest exe, which is not replacing it.

Comment: If this is VS setup project  to generate an MSI file (which isn't obvious from your question) and you are doing a RemovePreviousVersions upgrade, then data files that have been modified after installation will not be replaced. Does this describe your problem?